# What is the difference between ESO: Tamriel Unlimited and ESO: Gold Edition?

Tags: steam, version-differences, the-elder-scrolls-online

The Elder Scrolls Online: Tamriel Unlimited and The Elder Scrolls Online: Gold Edition are listed separately on Steam. What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Tamriel Unlimited** is simply the vanilla game on its own. It was added as a subtitle/tagline when it switched from monthly subscriptions to a one time cost to play. It's the main game and there is nothing remarkable about it.

**Gold Edition** comes bundled with 4 DLC Game Packs.

> **DLC game packs:**
>    - Imperial City
>    - Orsinium
>    - Thieves Guild
>    - Dark Brotherhood